# Riddle: You don't always get me right

Tags: riddle

> To this riddle one shall add "meta"
>   Like a program and an SE site
>   For the answer you have some data
>   Yet not always you will get it right

Trying out an "ABAB" rhyming scheme here.

I guess I'm not good at judging difficulty, so please excuse me if this is too easy or too hard.

Hint 1:

> The answer itself contains no "meta", nor will it make sense if it does.

Hint 2:

> "Data" means raw, unprocessed information, it may or may not be computer data.

Comment: Are you looking for a number? Because to me I'm headed to the SE data explorer and looking for *something* at *programmers.SE*

Comment: @Raystafarian Nope. It has nothing to do with programmers.SE, and data means raw, unprocessed information, not computer data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is:

> This riddle

To this riddle one shall add "meta"

> Meta means self-referencing. This riddle is referencing itself.

Like a program and an SE site

> Could be referring to [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/26107/riddle-you-dont-always-get-me-right?rq=1) and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

For the answer you have some data

> The clues are data.

Yet not always you will get it right

> I sure get most riddles wrong! :P

Hint 1:

> Anyone heard of a meta-riddle?

Hint 2:

> The clues directly from a riddle are quite "raw" in the sense that it takes a lot of processing to understand them.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my guess:

> Analysis

Reasoning:

Line 1: 
To this riddle one shall add "meta"

> You can add "meta" to analysis to get "meta-analysis", a type of statistical analysis.

Line 2: 
Like a program and an SE site

> There's a program at meta-analysis.com for meta-analyses of data. There's also a "meta" site on SE and a number of SE sites that are devoted to data analysis.

Line 3: 
For the answer you have some data

> You need data in order to do an analysis

Line 4: 
Yet not always you will get it right

> Analyses are not always right. In fact, many analyses use a p-value of .05, which (sort of) means that you'll be wrong about 5% of the time. (That's a simplification, but we'll roll with it for now.)

Comment: I like it, plus it matches up with mine a bit.

Comment: You can also add meta to data for other types of analysis

Answer (score 5):

Bit of a long shot, but I think the answer is:

> Estimate

To this riddle one shall add "meta"

> 'est' or 'esti' translates as 'this' in some languages and 'mate' is an anagram of 'meta', so depending on whether or not we use the 'one' in the clue we have 'est'+'i'+'mate' or 'esti'+'mate'.

Like a program and an SE site

> programme is like program in how it's pronounced and in some definitions but with an extra 'me'. Adding to 'an', we get 'mean' (this part may need more explanation). SE refers to Standard Error and a mean and standard error are part and parcel of an estimate. The word 'site' can also combine with 'meta' to make 'estimate', playing into the theme of a 'meta' riddle.

For the answer you have some data

> An estimate needs some input data. The riddle's first two lines also yield words useful for creating the 'estimate' anagram. Also, 'at' is some of data which we can combine with letters yielded from the last line.

Yet not always you will get it right

> If you estimate, you don't always get it right. Also, 'not always' could be a synonym for sometimes and the 'right' of sometimes could be 'etimes'. Combining this with the 'at' of line three we can rearrange to again get 'estimate'.

Comment: It's not the correct answer, but it's very amazing how you can put these things together, albeit a little far-fetched.

Answer (score 3):

If the last line  `Yet not always you will get it right` indicates the whole world including meta, 
then my answer is

> Metaphor

I don't get it right all the times.

Comment: Sry but it took me long enough. I added a hint, I guess your answer is because of a misunderstanding so it should be fine to make a second guess.

Comment: @busukxuan Does adding meta to answer makes a sensible word?

Comment: Well, not really

Answer (score 3):

I'm going with

> reference

```
To this riddle one shall add "meta"
Like a program and an SE site
```

> Adding meta to something makes it about itself. SE sites are all `*.SE.com`

```
For the answer you have some data 
Yet not always you will get it right
```

> Referencing data in a hypothesis is required - but doesn't make the hypothesis correct.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is:

> Physics

To this riddle one shall add "meta"
Like a program and an SE site

> If you prepend "meta" to "physics", you get "metaphysics".

For the answer you have some data
Yet not always you will get it right

> In "metaphysics", you have some data but it is not always facts and you often come up with scientific theories. Thus, you are not always right.